# Как остановить SQL запрос

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Я делаю запрос в базу данных `"SELECT * FROM USER_FM WHERE PHONE = ? OR EMAIL = ?"`. База данных `ORACLE`. Подскажите, могу я остановить выполнение запроса после нахождения первого совпадения ? Если да, то как.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/1051621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> могу я остановить выполнение запроса после нахождения первого
>   совпадения ?

Вы можете сделать запрос на выдачу только первого вхождения с помощью ROWNUM (тогда останавливать ничего не придётся):

```
"SELECT * FROM USER_FM WHERE (PHONE = ? OR EMAIL = ?) AND ROWNUM <=1"
```

[Источник](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-first/)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я протупил с вопросом. В этом случае надо просто получить один объект из базы при первом совпадении, то есть использовать `getSingleResult()`. Но всё равно, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: *надо просто получить один объект из базы* С показанным запросом это - бессмысленное действие. Потому что результат недетерминирован. Укажите сортировку, которая обеспечивает уникальность.

Comment: Akina, то есть надо добавить `ORDER BY` ?